# Allow Admin to safely customize UI and Logic of app via Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, isv, invocable-method

This is not a question about the general feasibility of a single aspect of my question. I know that and how they work. I am interested in real-world experience from AppExchange Partners on how to allow Subscriber Org Admins to extend part of the logic and UI of a Managed Package app using Headless and Screen Flows. In a safe and clean way. Maintainable, testable and extendable.

[image]

**I am interested in hearing and collecting wisdom about what looked promising but didn't work and what was surprisingly successful in ISV reality.**

Here are a few thoughts and assumptions that I have:

1. Is it beneficial to break down monolithic app code and expose parts as `Invocables`?
2. Should such methods use packaged Custom Objects or Apex Types as Input/Output?
3. Is there a way to prevent exposing global Apex types?
4. When does extracting code logic as overridable Flows make sense?
5. Should packaged Flows be `Templates` or marked as `Overridable`?
6. Should customizable UI elements be Flow Screens or should LWCs embed Flow Screens?
7. Should CMDT types be used to define Flow overrides or directly queried via Tooling A PI?
8. How do such flow-code parts affect app performance and maintainability?
9. What else is relevant or less relevant than most people think?

Comment: I really, really don't get the close votes on this question. What is the issue with a deeply thought, well-grounded question where people clearly need more answers? What could ever motivate somebody to shut down somebody to ask a bit broader, less technical, yes/no questions? In my opinion, it must be a wrong understanding of power, a misuse of voting ability and a clear interest to harm to sharing of knowledge. Thos who close vote please come out and tell me where else I should ask for such a dialog?